# How to override attribute from embedded column is superclass

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to override a property of an embedded column existing in the superclass of an entity.

My entities look like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class Key {
    @Column
    private String a,

    @Column
    private String b
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Superclass {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Key key;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@AttributeOverride(name = "b", column = @Column(name="renamed_b"))
public class MyEntity extends Superclass {

}
```

I have tried using [AttributeOverride](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) on MyEntity, but it doesn't do anything.

It would work if I would move the AttributeOverride annotation on the embedded field, but I cannot modify the superclass.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, read documentation carefully:

> To override mappings at multiple levels of embedding, a dot (".")
>   notation form must be used in the name element to indicate an
>   attribute within an embedded attribute.

The name `"b"` is incorrect. 
You should use `"key.b"`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@AttributeOverride(name = "key.b", column = @Column(name="renamed_b"))
public class MyEntity extends Superclass 
}
```